# Just starting on Solana and would greatly appreciate any tips!(:

Tags: wallet, staking, instructions

I am just starting with Solana and if anyone could give me any pointers or some sort or direction that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://solana.com/developers

Answer (score 1):

https://solanacookbook.com/#contributing

Check this out, lots of good early examples. Also the anchor repository is a useful place to understand more along with popular projects that have open source frontend applications.